# Swift retain cycle explanation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

Here is my custom view:

```
class CustomVIew: UIView {

    deinit {
        print("custom view deinit")
    }

    var onTapViewHandler: (()->Void)?
}
```

and the View Controller:

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    var customView: CustomVIew!

    deinit {
        print("B deinit")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let customView = CustomVIew()
        customView.onTapViewHandler = { [unowned self] in
            self.didTapBlue()
        }
        customView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 250, width: 200, height: 100)
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        view.addSubview(customView)

        self.customView = customView

    }

    func didTapBlue() {

    }
}
```

When the controller is popped from the navigation stack, everything is fine:

```
B deinit
custom view deinit
```

But when I replace this code:

```
customView.onTapViewHandler = { [unowned self] in
     self.didTapBlue()
}
```

with this:

```
 customView.onTapViewHandler = didTapBlue
```

then, nothing is printed on the console. The CustomView and ViewController are not released, why?

Why does `customView.onTapViewHandler = didTapBlue` capture a reference to `self`?

Comment: You know why already isnt it? Your title says it is retain circle...check the reference count by print it: print(CFGetRetainCount(object))

Comment: @Surely you suggest `CFGetRetainCount` to work around `retain` being deprecated. But there is a reason that `retain` is deprecated: This is not a good solution.

Comment: It is just a checking method. I mean you can print out the amount of references that view controller is been referenced so that you know whether the "customView" has a strong reference to the view controller. If it has, there is a retain cycle. Because it has a retain cycle, the two object cannot be destroyed automatically.

Comment: @Surely Never check `CFGetRetainCount`. The information you get is not useful. For example, just the way `CFGetRetainCount` is imported into Swift makes it increase all results by 1. Never check retain count. Even the documentation says so.

Comment: @Sulthan It is not the number matters, it is whether the number increase matters. I have used it to count the reference, it is useful to determine whether a line of code increase the object's reference count, hence I know whether it will cause problem. And this code is just for debugging, I dont mean you will keep this code when you release the app. Without count the reference, I am quite curious how do you debug such problem?

Answer (score 6):

Swift function is a type of closure. So like closure(Block in objective c) does functions can capture references.

when `customView.onTapViewHandler = didTapBlue` gets executes a reference to `self` ie `ViewControllerB` reference in this case will be captured by the function call.

Same time `ViewControllerB`'s view holds strong reference to `CustomVIew` so it makes retain cycle.

About using `unowned`, [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID52) says:

> Weak and unowned references enable one instance in a reference cycle
>   to refer to the other instance without keeping a strong hold on it.
>   The instances can then refer to each other without creating a strong
>   reference cycle.

That means no circular reference and retain cycle.

Comment: thanks.I just don't understand why `customView.onTapViewHandler = didTapBlue` executes will captures `self`' reference, can you tell me?

Comment: `didTapBlue` is `self.didTapBlue`. So  `customView` should hold reference to `didTapBlue`, only then it could execute that function. As you know, didTapBlue can not survive without a reference to the object. So closures, blocks and methods add a strong reference to the instance

Answer (score 5):

If you add the `[unowned self]` capture list to the closure, the view holds a weak reference to `self`, and `self` holds a strong reference to the view.

Since nothing has a strong reference to `self`, `self` can be deinitialized when the view controller is popped. After `self` is deinitialized, nothing has a strong reference to the view anymore, so *it* is deinitialized too.

If you remove the capture list, `self` holds a strong reference to the view and the view holds a strong reference to `self`. This means that in order to deinitialize `self`, the view must be deinitialized first (which will break the strong reference). But in order for the view to be deinitialized, the view controller must be deinitialized first to break the strong reference to the view. But you can't break the strong reference to the view unless you deinitialize the view controller. You can't break the strong reference to the view controller unless you deinitialize the view.

See? We have gotten into an infinite loop here! So neither the view nor the view controller will be deinitialized!